# How can I run perf inside LinuxKit (Docker for Mac)?

Tags: docker, perf, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

I have Docker for Mac with LinuxKit kernel version `4.9.125-linuxkit`.

`perf` is not available on the host. I tried to install it on one of my Ubuntu containers but I'm unable to get the versioned `linux-tools` package for the `4.9.125` kernel. So when I try to run perf, I just get

`WARNING: perf not found for kernel 4.9.125`

Is there a way to run `perf` on my LinuxKit/Hyperkit host, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5):

Create the image

```
docker build -t myubuntu - <<EOF 
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic gcc wget vim
RUN ln -fs /usr/lib/linux-tools/*/perf /usr/bin/perf
EOF
```

And then run: `docker run --cap-add SYS_ADMIN -it myubuntu /bin/bash`